# Unable to download update for Yureka YU

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have downloaded more than once yureka upgrade to `cyanogen 12 based Lollipop 5.1` but my OS is not being updated. I have tried rebooting the phone after download but to no effect. I am still using old version. Unable to download new version. Please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hard to say without some more details: What Android version (and ROM) have you currently running? What steps did you do to download? Where there any instructions you've been following?

Answer (score 0):

below are not be done before you upgrade:
Rooting, developer mode on, phone memory full - if this is exist then you cant update and the downloaded file must be kept in phone/download not on sd.

If your downloading from OTA then this are not to do list: and to make you simple download from google and place it on the download place in phone memory then you give it a try if this helped you fine else tell me were have you done mistakes so that clearly I can suggest you. as of mine updated and running smooth.

Comment: Can you make it  bit more presentable by using http://android.stackexchange.com/editing-help Its good  that you're helping and the method worked for you, but if the answer cannot be understood easily, the answer might not be considered useful.